# Can't use Split View with TextWrangler

Tags: macos, split-view, bbedit

I just updated TextWrangler to the latest version (5.5.1 (3944)) but Split View does not work. As I see they promote a new editor - BBEdit, so I guess they don't care about this one? Or is it possible somehow to enable Split View?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not switching to the free tier of BBEdit? Have you [contacted Bare Bones Software](http://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/index.html) about this problem?

Comment: I haven't contacted them, I think it would be good to get the answer to this question (if it is) in public, since now, googling this issue just brings you to sites full of adds that only pretend they provide the answer. And BBEdit I do not download for few reasons: 1. I like TextWrangler (used to it), 2. BBEdit comes in a full-package just for 30 days, so I am afraid to get annoyed with adds to buy it after that period finishes.

Comment: I recommend contacting Bare Bones directly and then sharing the answer they provide here. You can also take the opportunity to tell them about your concerns regarding purchase prompts with BBEdit's free tier.

Comment: I guess you are right. If no one will answer this I will do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of Split View is noted in Bare Bone's [Text Wrangler FAQ](https://www.barebones.com/support/textwrangler/faqs.html#splitview). It's a limitation in El Capitan and Sierra that affects both Text Wrangler and [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/faqs.html#splitview).